# Cannot assign PHP variable to mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli

So I'm trying to echo each row of users from one of my databases at a website I recently set up on my WAMP Server, version 2.5. I could be wrong, but I've Googled and also search this site's posts... I don't think there's been a problem quite like this one addressed yet.

In my practice of using PHP by following tutorials/exercises, I had of course found that MySQL prefers either PDO or MySQLi these days, so I decided to give a shot at using MySQLi.

The weird thing is, I've included the PHP file that configures the MySQL connection, and I know the connection variable is being called properly, since I've even printed out the result of the query that the variable was being assigned to:

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 3 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )
```

Above is the output when I use:

```
 print_r($db_con->query("SELECT * FROM users"));
```

Yet when I try to assign the result to a variable, like $user_rs, and print the value of that variable, I get "Notice: Undefined variable: user_rs in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 58."

Here are my files.

dbconfig.php:

```
<?php
    $db_con= new mysqli("localhost","root","abc123", "OTonGadgetHub");
    if($db_con->connect_errno){
        echo $db_con->connect_error;

    }

?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php session_start();
include ("dbconfig.php"); ?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "site.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="index.html?img=favicon" type="image/ico" />
    <script>
            function validatingForm(){
                var x;
                var y;
                x = document.getElementById('nameCheck').value;
                y = document.getElementById('password').value;
                if(x !="" && y !=""){
                    return true;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y == ""){
                        document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        document.getElementById('errorPass').innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(x =="" && y!=""){
                        document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                        document.getElementById('errorPass').innerHTML='<font color="blue">Password:</font>';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else if(y =="" && x!=""){
                        document.getElementById('errorPass').innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                        document.getElementById('errorMsg').innerHTML='<font color="blue">Name:</font>';
                        return false;
                        }

            }
        </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php include("header.php"); ?>
                <?php

                if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
                        echo "<p class ='welcome' id='greeting'> Hi, ". $_SESSION['user'] . "! Welcome to the site!</p>";
                else
                        echo "<p class ='welcome' id='greeting'> Please Login:</p>
                                        <form action='welcome.php' method='post'>
                                            <center><b id = 'errorMsg'>Name:</b>
                                            <input type='text' id='nameCheck' name = 'username' /></center>
                                            <br />
                                            <center><b id='errorPass'>Password:</b> <input type='text' id ='password' name = 'password'/></center>
                                            <br /><br />
                                            <center><input type='submit' value='Log In' onClick='return validatingForm()'/></center>
                                        </form>";
                ?>
            <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
            $user_rs = $db_con->query("SELECT * FROM users");
                print_r($db_con->query("SELECT * FROM users"));
                print_r($user_rs);
                echo "<center><h1> User List:</h1>
                    <table border='1'>
                    <tr>
                    <td><b>User</b></td>
                    <td><b>Login password</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>";
                    while($record = $user_rs->fetch_object()){
                        echo "<td>" . $record['id'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['username'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    echo"</table></center>";
            ?>
            <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
                echo "<center><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></center>";?>  

            <p class = "content"> This is a page that is a scrap work in progress. </p>


            <?php include("footer.php"); ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

I have other files, but believe these to be outside the scope of the problem. I will however be happy to supply the other files if requested.

A REMINDER: My concern is the fact that I cannot essentially use the result that should have been assigned to $user_rs . Mainly, it appears to be nothing even though I appear to have assigned it to the query correctly. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You're fetching $record as an object, but trying to display it as though it was an array: `$record->id` and `$record->username`

Comment: As @Mark says - try this syntax: `$record->id` and `$record->username` ~ but why run the query twice?

Comment: @RamRaider why run the query twice? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: I like your points about using the mysqli object syntax to fetch properties of said object, and I've changed my code accordingly. However, that still doesn't answer the million dollar question of why I can't appear to assign that to a variable. I also noticed that changing the syntax to the property syntax also repeats the one record that exists in the users table infinitely. Did I miss another detail?

Comment: You use `print_r($db_con->query("SELECT * FROM users"));` directly after running the query for the first time

Comment: @RamRaider that's because I wanted to be sure that the query itself was working and the problem lied with the variable assigning to the running of such a query. And the point is that for some weird reason I've found that that's exactly what the problem appears to be. NOTE: if I set the variable inside dbconfig and call it from the index file, the PHP server returns the set variable perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a typo-like error.

In essence, it asks how to assign a variable to an expression result, and the answer is as obvious as it can be:

```
$user_rs = $db_con->query("SELECT * FROM users");
```

and the particular problem in question can be bolied down to

> "Why am I getting `Undefined variable: user_rs` error from the code below

```
        $user_rs = $db_con->query("SELECT * FROM users");
        print_r($user_rs);
```

and the answer would be "that's just impossible".

check the file you are running and the stuff like that.

Comment: You have an excellent point regarding this kind of error, it should NOT be happening to my knowledge. I have attempted setting a variable inside dbconfig after much frustration, and for some reason calling that variable works just fine. It makes me think it's a strange scope problem. Maybe a character misread in my PHP file?

Answer (score 0):

Your db query was fetching the recordset as an object yet you were trying to reference the fields using an array syntax.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "site.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="index.html?img=favicon" type="image/ico" />
    <script>
        function validatingForm(){
            var x;
            var y;
            var e;
            var p;

            x = document.getElementById('nameCheck').value;
            y = document.getElementById('password').value;
            e = document.getElementById('errorMsg');
            p = document.getElementById('errorPass');

            if(x !="" && y !=""){
                return true;
             } else if(x =="" && y == ""){
                    e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                    p.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                    return false;
             } else if(x =="" && y!=""){
                    e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Name:</font>';
                    p.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Password:</font>';
                    return false;
             } else if(y =="" && x!=""){
                    e.innerHTML='<font color="red">(required) Password:</font>';
                    p.innerHTML='<font color="blue">Name:</font>';
                    return false;
             }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
        include("header.php");

        if ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ){
            /* Use is logged in */
            echo "
                <p class ='welcome' id='greeting'>
                    Hi, ". $_SESSION['user'] . "! Welcome to the site!
                </p>";
        } else {

            /* User is NOT logged in */
            echo "
                <p class ='welcome' id='greeting'> Please Login:</p>
                <form action='welcome.php' method='post'>
                    <center>
                        <b id = 'errorMsg'>Name:</b>
                        <input type='text' id='nameCheck' name = 'username' />
                    </center>
                    <br />
                    <center>
                    <b id='errorPass'>Password:</b>
                            <input type='text' id ='password' name = 'password'/>
                    </center>
                        <br /><br />
                    <center>
                        <input type='submit' value='Log In' onClick='return validatingForm()'/>
                    </center>
                </form>";
        }


        if ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ){

            /* Query the db, once! */
            $user_rs = $db_con->query("SELECT * FROM `users`;");

            /* Assume there is a recordset and create the table */
            echo "
                <center>
                    <h1> User List:</h1>
                    <table border='1'>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>User</b></td>
                            <td><b>Login password</b></td>
                        </tr>";

                /* loop through recordset - new row for each user */
                while( $record = $user_rs->fetch_object() ){
                    echo "
                        <tr>
                            <td>" . $record->id . "</td>
                            <td>" . $record->username . "</td>
                        </tr>";
                }
                /* Close the table */
                echo "
                    </table>
                </center>";
        }

        if ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ) echo "<center><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></center>";
?>  

            <p class = "content"> This is a page that is a scrap work in progress. I WILL use CSS to do my presentation in future '-)</p>


        <?php 
            include("footer.php");
        ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for giving me pointers and directions regarding this problem.

I did really like the answers that were given, but not for the reasons that someone might think if I accepted RamRaider's answer.

So I thought I'd put it as the actual answer to a question. My problem appeared to be that I was not clearly defining the scope to PHP with the curly brackets. I left those out of my code, and as a result, it appeared to become confused when I left out the brackets for my if statement checking a user session. Poor PHP server :( I really did abuse it.

If your scope for an if-else statement is long (spanning more than say one or two lines of code), ALWAYS find a way to enclose the scope with the right syntax. Otherwise you're in for a rough ride.

That being said, an excellent point was made regarding querying the database only once and calling the properties as if I was querying the object, which was still helpful to me as a rookie. Take heed of that comment when writing mysqli statements as well.

Thanks very much everyone.